# How to append a file and take out a specific line python 3

Tags: python, file, python-3.x, dictionary, append

I have a stock file in the format of this:

```
12345678,Fridge,1,50
23456789,Car,2,50
34567890,TV,20,50
```

This is the code:

```
def main():
products = {}
#This is the file directory being made.
f = open('stockfile.txt') 
#This is my file being opened.

for line in f:


    # Need to strip to eliminate end of line character
    line = line[:-1]
    #This gets rid of the character which shows and end of line '\n'
    row = line.split(',')
    #The row is split by the comma
    products[row[0]] = [row[1], row[2],row[3]]
    #The products are equal to row 1 and row 2 and row 3. The GTIN is going to take the values of the product and price so GTIN 12345678 is going to correspond to Fridge and 1.

print(products)
total = 0

print('Id       Description         Total')
while True:
    GTIN = input('Please input GTIN ')
    if(GTIN not in products):
        print('Sorry your code was invalid, try again:')
        break

    row = products[GTIN]
    print(GTIN)
    description = row[0]
    value = row[1]
    stock = row[2]
    print(stock)

    quantity = input('Please also input your quantity required: ')
    row[2]= int(stock) - int(quantity)
    products[row[2]] = row[2]
    product_total= (int(quantity)*int(value))
    New_Stock  = GTIN + ',' + description + ',' + value + ',' + str(products[row[2]])
    f = open('stockfile.txt','r')
    lines = f.readlines()
    f.close()
    f = open("stockfile.txt","a")
    for row in lines:
        if((row + '\n') != (New_Stock + '\n')):
            f.write(New_Stock)
            f.close()

    print('%20s%20s%20s' % (GTIN, description, product_total))

    total = total + product_total

print('Total of the order is £%s' % total)
print(products)
main()
```

However, the code doesn't update the stock's. What it should do is get rid of the previous stock for the product given and then update it according to the quantity the user has just bought.

I haven't got to it yet but once the stock hits zero I need my code to then tell the user that we have run out of stock and need some new stock. Then there needs to be a message to the user to wait until we restock and then display the price of restocking as well.

If you have time please could you make this new bit of code as well but if not could you just explain how to update the stock and why my code isn't working, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you `seek` to a given line and call `write`, in order to completely overwrite that line, without affecting other lines or inadvertently creating new lines, each line in your stock must have a fixed width. How do you ensure fixed width? By giving each field in the record a fixed width. Basically, you choose a maximum number of characters each field can have; here I'll assume 8 for all fields (though they must not all be the same), so your stock will be stored this way:

```
12344848,  Fridge,       2,      50
13738389,      TV,       5,      70
```

If you keep going this way, each line will have a maximum width which will enable you to seek to the start of the line and overwrite it completely. Try this code:

```
MAX_FIELD_LEN = 8

def main():
    products = {}
    product_location  = {}
    location = 0
    # This is the file directory being made.
    with open('stockfile.txt', 'r+') as f:
        # This is my file being opened.

        for line in f:
            # keep track of each products location in file  to overwrite with New_Stock
            product_location[line.split(',')[0]] = location
            location += len(line)
            # Need to strip to eliminate end of line character
            line = line[:-1]
            # This gets rid of the character which shows and end of line '\n'
            row = line.split(',')
            # The row is split by the comma
            products[row[0]] = [row[1], row[2], row[3]]
            # The products are equal to row 1 and row 2 and row 3. The GTIN is going to take the values of the product and price so GTIN 12345678 is going to correspond to Fridge and 1.

        print(products)
        total = 0

        while True:
            GTIN = input('Please input GTIN: ')
            # To terminate user input, they just need to press ENTER
            if GTIN == "":
                break
            if (GTIN not in products):
                print('Sorry your code was invalid, try again:')
                break

            row = products[GTIN]
            description, value, stock = row
            print('Stock data: ')
            print('GTIN \t\tDesc. \t\tStock \t\tValue')
            print(GTIN,'\t',description,'\t', stock, '\t', value)

            quantity = input('Please also input your quantity required: ')
            row[2] = str(int(stock) - int(quantity))
            product_total = int(quantity) * int(value)
            for i in range(len(row)):  
                row[i]  = row[i].rjust(MAX_FIELD_LEN)
            New_Stock = GTIN.rjust(MAX_FIELD_LEN) + ',' + ','.join(row) + '\n'
            #print(New_Stock, len(New_Stock))
            f.seek(product_location[GTIN])
            f.write(New_Stock)
            print('You bought: {0} {1} \nCost: {2}'.format(GTIN, description, product_total))

            total = total + product_total
        f.close()
        print('Total of the order is £%s' % total)

main()
```

Ensure that each field in the TXT file is exactly 8 characters wide (not including the commas) when using this program. If you want to increase the field width, change the `MAX_FIELD_LEN` variable accordingly. Your TXT file should look like this:

[image: TXT FILE]

Comment: I'm still getting the same problem though unfortunately even after adding that.

Comment: @HC123 Can you post your code? As well as your text file when you get this error?

Comment: Sorry, I don't seem to able to for some reason... Could you try and incorporate your code into mine and post it along with the file, please. I don't seem to be able to post for some reason. @TisteAndii

Comment: Unfortunately I still get the same problem: products[row[0]] = [row[1], row[2], row[3]]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @HC123 I tried the code on my PC with the sample I showed you and it worked perfectly. Did it work for you at all? Edit your post to show the sample TXT file you are using. Also know that there should be no extra lines in your TXT file; make sure you use BACKSPACE to ensure that the last line is the last line containing stock.

Comment: I posted another question which is very similar to this but only with a csv file, I was wondering if you could take a look as I don't understand why I can't paste the dictionary back to the csv without this problem

Answer (score 0):

In the first few lines you are loading the whole data file in memory :

```
for line in f:
    products[row[0]] = [row[1], row[2],row[3]]
```

So then just update the data in memory, and have users enter a special command : "save" to write the whole list to your file.

You could also catch your application process KILL signal so if a user hits ctrl + c, you can ask him if he wants to save before quitting.

And maybe save a temporary copy of the list to a file every few seconds.

Comment: How would you do that @Loïc, could you maybe show a code?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the `shelve` module for this, if your customers intend to run this program many times. Reading the whole file into memory and writing it anew as text will become inefficient as your stock grows. `Shelve` creates persistent files (3 files to be exact) on your PC for storing your data. Most importantly, `shelve` would give you the same `dict` interface you want, so that all you have to do is call `shelve.open()` on the file and you can begin accessing/updating your stock using GTINs as keys. Its very straightforward, just look at the python manuals. If you really want a text file, you could have your program, iterate through the `shelve` file containing your stock (same as for a dictionary) and write keys (GTIN) and their values (your stock quantity) to a text file you opened. This way, you have easy intuitive access to your records and also a readable format in your TXT file.

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion above using shelve sounds like a good idea, but if you want to keep your file as is but only update the records that are changed (instead of rewriting the whole file each time) using (most) of your code, this seems to work.

```
def main():
    products = {}
    product_location  = {}
    location = 0
    # This is the file directory being made.
    with open('stockfile.txt', 'r+') as f:
        # This is my file being opened.

        for line in f:
            # keep track of each products location in file  to overwrite with New_Stock
            product_location[line.split(',')[0]] = location
            location += len(line)
            # Need to strip to eliminate end of line character
            line = line[:-1]
            # The row is split by the comma
            row = line.split(',')
            products[row[0]] = [row[1], row[2], row[3]]
            """
            The products are equal to row 1 and row 2 and row 3. The GTIN is going to take the values of the product and
            price so GTIN 12345678 is going to correspond to Fridge and 1.
            """

        print(sorted(products.items()))
        total = 0

        while True:
            GTIN = input('\nPlease input GTIN or press [Enter] to quit:\n')
            # To terminate user input, they just need to press ENTER
            if GTIN == "":
                break
            if (GTIN not in products):
                # Let the user continue with order after mistake in GTIN input
                print('Sorry your code was invalid, try again:')
                continue

            row = products[GTIN]
            print('GTIN:', GTIN)
            description = row[0]
            value = row[1]
            stock = row[2]
            stock_length = len(row[2])
            backorder = 0
            print('In Stock:', stock)

            quantity = input('Please also input your quantity required:\n')
            if int(quantity) > int(stock):
                row[2] = 0
                backorder = int(quantity) - int(stock)
                # TO DO
                Backordered_Stock = GTIN + ',' + description + ',' + value + ',' + str(backorder) + '\n'
            else:
                row[2] = int(stock) - int(quantity)
            products[row[2]] = row[2]
            product_total = (int(quantity) * int(value))
            New_Stock = GTIN + ',' + description + ',' + value + ',' + str(products[row[2]]).rjust(stock_length) + '\n'
            f.seek(product_location[GTIN])
            f.write(New_Stock)
            print('Ordered - {0:>6} GTIN: {1:>10}  Desc: {2:<20}  at £{3:>6}  Total value: £{4:>6}  On backorder: {5:>4}'.
                format(int(quantity), GTIN, description, int(value), product_total, backorder))

            total = total + product_total

        print('Total of the order is £%s' % total)

main()
```

Comment: You could end up overwriting part of the next line, if your NewStock is longer than the current line, or you may get extra characters in the same line if NewStock is too short. This will only work if each line has a fixed length. There isnt any way to selectively update the file, except by giving each field in a record a fixed width, adding padding where necessary.

Comment: The code worked however for some reason it stopped working... it now comes up with this: 
    products[row[0]] = [row[1], row[2], row[3]]
    IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: For some reason the code stopped working? @TisteAndii

Comment: It does that because you have overwritten parts of other lines, thereby upsetting the uniformity of the code. If you want this to work, i'll post an answer to help

Comment: Please could you do that, it would be really helpful! @TisteAndii

Comment: Regarding TisteAndii's comments that all lines needing to be fixed width - that is not quite correct.  I did test my code with the following file:12345678,Fridge,1,50
23456789,Car,2,50
34567890,TV,20,50
4567890123,Boat,30,50
456789,Microwave,3,50

Comment: Regarding TisteAndii's comments that all lines needing to be fixed width - that is not quite correct.  I did test my code with the following file:12345678,Fridge,1,50
23456789,Car,2,50
34567890,TV,20,50
4567890123,Boat,30,50
456789,Microwave,3,50 and it worked fine, EXCEPT, I later realised, if the length of stock remaining changes, and it's the only field that can change given how the New_Stock line is built up.  So that is the only field that needs to be fixed width, so here TisteAndii is completely correct.  Line offsets are recalculated each time the program is run.  Sorry about my editing

Comment: That's no problem @MTSet , if possible could you edit your code so it works?

Comment: Hi HC123, requested changes made.  Also 'tidied up' output to user and user input requests, the product list at start is now displayed in sorted form, on incorrect GTIN input the user gets to carry on with the order rather than exiting, orders greater than stock reduce stock to zero, inform user and create a Backordered_Stock line for you to process.

Answer (score 0):

```
MAX_FIELD_LEN = 8

def main():
    products = {}
    product_location  = {}
    location = 0
    # This is the file directory being made.
    with open('stockfile.txt', 'r+') as f:
    # This is my file being opened.

    for line in f:
        # keep track of each products location in file  to overwrite with New_Stock
        product_location[line.split(',')[0]] = location
        location += len(line)
        # Need to strip to eliminate end of line character
        line = line[:-1]
        # This gets rid of the character which shows and end of line '\n'
        row = line.split(',')
        # The row is split by the comma
        products[row[0]] = [row[1], row[2], row[3]]
        # The products are equal to row 1 and row 2 and row 3. The GTIN is going to take the values of the product and price so GTIN 12345678 is going to correspond to Fridge and 1.

    print(products)
    total = 0

    while True:
        GTIN = input('Please input GTIN: ')
        # To terminate user input, they just need to press ENTER
        if GTIN == "":
            break
        if (GTIN not in products):
            print('Sorry your code was invalid, try again:')
            break

        row = products[GTIN]
        description, value, stock = row
        print('Stock data: ')
        print('GTIN \t\tDesc. \t\tStock \t\tValue')
        print(GTIN,'\t',description,'\t', stock, '\t', value)

        quantity = input('Please also input your quantity required: ')
        row[2] = str(int(stock) - int(quantity))
        product_total = int(quantity) * int(value)
        for i in range(len(row)):  
            row[i]  = row[i].rjust(MAX_FIELD_LEN)
        New_Stock = GTIN.rjust(MAX_FIELD_LEN) + ',' + ','.join(row) + '\n'
        #print(New_Stock, len(New_Stock))
        f.seek(product_location[GTIN])
        f.write(New_Stock)
        print('You bought: {0} {1} \nCost: {2}'.format(GTIN, description, product_total))

        total = total + product_total
    f.close()
    print('Total of the order is £%s' % total)

main()
```

This was the text file: 
   
    `12345678,  Fridge,       1,      50
    23456789,     Car,       2,      50
    34567890,      TV,      20,      50`

Does it make a difference I am doing this on a Mac desktop or that it is python 3.4.3?

Comment: @TisteAndii this was my code when I did the run and it is the code you posted.

Comment: I think it matters that you are using a Mac because pre-OSX Macs use a different line ending. Try replacing the `\n` in New_Stock (after the `for` loop) with `\r` (You can also try `\r\n`). Also change the lines: `location += len(line)` to `location = f.tell()` and `line = line[:-1]` to `line = line.rstrip()`